# When to use String and when char array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I am supposed to read a large file containing a string in each line. What is the best way to parse this kind of file in Java?

Currently I am parsing like this using `BufferedReader`:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String filename) {

    List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            input.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

So my question here is, which one is a better way: to save like an array of `String` or an array of `char` arrays?

In other words, is it better to have too many `String` objects or too many `char` arrays?

EDIT:
I need to check if the string in each line is a palindrome or not.

Comment: what is the purpose of the reading file ?

Comment: "*is it better to have too many String objects or too many char arrays*" define *better*.

Comment: which is better? It all depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: **Side note**: Assuming you are using at least Java 7, I'd use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to create your `BufferedReader`.

Comment: The code to read strings is certainly cleaner.  e.g. `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());`.  Unless you're going to want to be using the data as characters, I'd go with strings.  It's impossible to give a definitive answer without knowing more about what you need the file contents for, though.

Answer (score 0):

In above scenario, you can use either of these. If you want change the content further, then you have to use array of char because String is immutable in nature in java.